# Finding the centre of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a finite group generated by elements $a_1, a_2... a_{m-1}, \epsilon$, $m > 2$, which satisfy the equations $a_i^2=\epsilon\neq1, \epsilon^2=1, a_ia_j=\epsilon a_j a_i$ for $i \neq j$.

How do I work out the centre of G?

Apparently the centre is $ \{1, \epsilon \}$ if m is odd, and $\{1,\epsilon, a_1...a_{m-1}, \epsilon a_1...a_{m-1} \}$ if m is even.

I got up to showing that 1 and $\epsilon$ are in the centre, but can't work out where to start for the different cases.

Answer (score 0):

First, show that every element in this group can be written uniquely in the form $$a_1^{x_1}a_2^{x_2}\cdots a_{m-1}^{x_{m-1}}\epsilon^{x_m}$$ 
with 
$$x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\in \{0,1\}.$$
(In particular, the group has order $2^m$.)
Then, consider some element $z=a_1^{x_1}a_2^{x_2}\cdots a_{m-1}^{x_{m-1}}\epsilon^{x_m}$ and suppose that $z$ is in the center.

Now, compute the commutator of $z$ with each of the generators. (This is easy to do because the commutator subgroup is central.) Since $z$ is central, these must be the identity which gives you some equations $\pmod 2$, and solving the system of equations yields the result.

For example, $1=[z,a_1]=\epsilon^{x_2+\cdots+x_{m-1}}$ hence $x_2+\cdots+x_{m-1}\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $z^{x_1+x_2+....x_{m-1}}$? Also, after the system of equations, I only get that it is true if m-2 is even or $x_1+x_2+....x_{m-1}$ is even? Doesn't that imply that, if m is even, all the elements are in the centre?

Comment: I did not write $z^{x_1+x_2+\ldots x_{m-1}}$. How about you write up what you have, and we can help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $z^{x_2+...+x_{m-1}}$. I don't really get how $z^{-1}a_1^{-1}za_1=z^{x_2+...+x_{m−1}}$. Apart from that I think I understand. From the system of equations, you get that $x_1\equiv x_2 \equiv x_3... \equiv x_{m-1}$ (mod 2), so $z$ is $1$ or $a_1a_2...a_{m_1}$. You also get $x_1+...+x_{m−1}=m-1 \equiv 1$ (mod 2), when $z$ isn't 1, so $a_1a_2...a_{m-1}$ isn't in the m odd case. Right?

Comment: Sorry, that $z$ should have been an $\epsilon$. I've edited it.